# Do LLMs also support weight modification like image generators?

Tags: llm

For instance, using "(n:2.0)" on a image generator prompt causes it to prioritize that thing on generation. Is this supportes on LLMs as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  The current generation of LLMs and the current generation of image generators work in very different ways.

At its core, StableDiffusion and other diffusion-based image generators are *image recognizers*.  They have a neural network trained to answer the question "to what degree does this image match the description?", and use some fancy math to figure out how to modify the image to improve the match.

With that structure, weighting makes sense: if you give "duck" twice the weight of "goose", any ambiguity in the generation process will tend to be resolved in favor of ducks rather than geese.

LLMs such as ChatGPT don't work that way.  They are trained to predict the best continuation of the input text, and behaviors such as "answering questions" or "writing in a given style" are purely side effects of that training.  Weighting the input doesn't make sense: the best continuation of "To be or not to be, that" doesn't change if you increase the emphasis on the "not".